# Buttons that toggle different column visualizations?

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-js

I have a census data table in Carto and I want the end user to be able to toggle through several different demographic visualizations via buttons on the map.

For example one button shows median age, another shows median income, etc. All of these are in the same table just different columns.

Any idea of how I would do this?

I am currently more of a GISer than a coder.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use CARTO.js, you can create a new datasets containing just the geometry and the target columns (`SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, median_age FROM table`, `SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, median_income FROM table` and so on). Then create a map with the new datasets created by those queries (remember that for free users 4 is the limit of layers). Finally, select `Layer selector` on the settings, then you will be able to toggle between these layers (or former fields).

Comment: thank you for the helpful info! If I was to use CARTO.js would I be able to have similiar functionality withtout creating multiple layers? I am tryinng to avoid running into the layer limit problem, even the 150 a month plan only allows for 5.